# How to replace video driver from System Recovery Console

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, recovery-console

I ran into a situation where my Lenovo T410 shows just a blank screen, even without a mouse cursor. I've documented the issue in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/203693/windows-7-suddenly-boots-to-a-shiny-blank-screen-on-a-lenovo-t410). I think that the issue, most probably, is caused by the NVidia driver. All my attempts to boot the system with anything displayed on both the laptop's LCD as well as on an external display failed.

Is there a way to replace the NVidia driver with a standard VGA driver using the System Recovery Console? This is the only boot option that works in my case.

Comment: Problem resolved: After several reboots, experiments, and trials to get the system display at least anything, Windows decided the boot process was corrupt and needed a repair. System restore spawned and rolled back to a previous configuration. I don't know what was the cause and also don't understand why earlier manual rollbacks to previous restore points from the System Recover Console didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any mention of this method in your other post

Boot into safemode using F8 (uses vga drivers) you should be able to uninstall the other drivers from there.

Comment: Safe mode doesn't work as it's using the current video driver (i.e. NVidia in my case), not the plain old good VGA driver. That one is used by the System Recovery Console and that's probably the only reason the console works.

Comment: It should not be using your NVidia driver in safe mode. Windows has a generic VGA driver that is used in safe mode. All windows video cards should support the standard VGA driver and boot to 640x480 resolution in safe mode. If the screen is blank in safe mode as well, you have a different problem. Once in safe mode, you should be able to install a different video driver.

Comment: @BBlake The behavior of the system pointed to the opposite, and I've found mentioning the 'current' video driver to be used in safe mode. However, I don't argue it and you might be right. The problem is now resolved — see my comment attached to the question.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting.  I've never heard that before.  As designed, Windows is supposed to used the generic standard VGA driver in safe mode and all windows video cards are required to support it for just such situations as this.  I wonder if NVidia or Lenovo is the one playing games with that.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to remove nvidia's files from system32/syswow64?

Comment: I had the same idea. However: 1) what files to remove in particular, 2) how to prevent system configuration corruption?